# How to remove some view from your view when you are scrolling your map?

Tags: android, google-maps-api-2

My layout contains google map v2 and some other content too.
I want to handle scroll of map V2 .I want to remove some of my view when user scroll the map and make them visible when user stop scrolling map. Any help .
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

just override scroll/touch, and there `.setVisibility(Viev.HIDE);`

Comment: there is no method for scroll or touch on map .How I can override this ?

Comment: your class should implement onScrollListener

Comment: on which should view i set this interface